# How detect any of all events using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function to detect idle state of user. I want to update database if any of the event occurs.Now i have script like this

```
$("body").mousemove(function(event) {
myfuction();
});
```

I want to convert above script like this

```
$("body").anyOfTheEvent(function(event) {
myfuction();
});
```

How can i do this?

Comment: **Why do you need to detect user's idle state?** It may be you're having a design flaw in your application because this may put your web application to crawl. Expecially if you'll wire Ajax requests to your events (mentioning DB). It will surely make it completely unusable. Believe me. All event's transferred to DB will surely halt it. A simple mouse move happens much more frequently than you can wire these events to the server and store them in the database.

Comment: I have a time limit in "Myfuction".only one Ajax request occur per 2 minute

Comment: Still: **Why do you need to detect user idle state?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the event name using the e.type property. Try looking this example

```
  $('#element').bind('click dblclick mousedown mouseenter mouseleave',
                     function(e){
                         alert("EventName:"+e.type);
                     });
    ​
```

The jsfiddle for this is here http://jsfiddle.net/qp2PP/

Answer (score 2):

You could have an array of the events you're interested in and subscribe to all of them

```
var events = ['click','mousemove','keydown'] // etc
$.each(events,function(i,e){
    $('body')[e](myfuction);    
});
```

Get a list of events here: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Answer (score 1):

You can bind more than one event with bind()

```
$('#foo').bind('click mousemove', function(evt) {
    console.log(evt.type);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just use `on()`, with a space-delimited list of events:

```
$('body').on('mousedown click', function(e) {
    var  eventType = e.type;
    // do stuff
});
```

References:

- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.org/on/).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of bind to specific element, you can bind directly to document.

```
$(document).bind('click mousemove', function(evt)       {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.random();
});
```

Example in [**CODEPEN**](https://codepen.io/radin/pen/Vzmawx?editors=1010#0)